# How to disable the line divider in the navigation menu?

Tags: java, android, listview, drop-down-menu

I want to disable the line divider in my navigation menu. I tried a code out, but it doesnt worked. I hope someone can help me :)
That is the code that I tried:

```
 <item name="android:listDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you have to add the Style :

```
<item name="android:listDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

but you have to define it as background in your divider view :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Add the layout of your navigationview and tell me what error message is displayed in LogCat @SinanKara

Comment: What is LogCat? Sorry but Iam new on Android Studio :D @Jorgesys

Comment: I tried it today again and it finally worked. Thanks you :) But is there a way where I can put horizontal lines at places where I want in my navigation view?